# AWS lambda VS AWS CLI

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

I would like to know which is the better option amongst these two techniques:

- Writing a function in EC2 instance using **AWS CLI**
- Writing a function using **AWS Lambda**

I prefer writing code in AWS Lambda, but I would like to know if there are any specific advantages on using Lambda.

P.S: Those functions that I have to execute are almost the same(they utilize the same algorithm), so there is no difference in the functionality.

Regards

Comment: AWS Lambda is used to define a function (you can test it, assign rights, import npm packages, manage memory etc.)

AWS CLI can be used to manage the list of lambda functions, invoke a lambda funciton, but you can't write complex server-side code in AWS-CLI, 

Take a look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-userapp.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would like to know if there is any particular advantage of using AWS Lambda instead of using EC2 Instances.

Here are some advantages of AWS Lambda:

- Reduced cost. Lambda follows a pay-as-you-invoke pricing model, unlike AWS EC2, and the first million invokes fall under the free tier category[1]. Depending on your use case, you might be able to save a lot using AWS Lambda on your production environment.
- No system administration payload. AWS Lambda follows serverless computing paradigms, and there's no need to start servers, configure them as per your need, and maintain them.
- An AWS Lambda function can be pretty convenient for automation tasks and can be triggered by a number of services[2]. Eg: If you upload a file to an AWS S3 bucket, you could choose to trigger a Lambda function that compresses the file and stores it in another S3 bucket.

However, Lambda has some disadvantages as well, compared to EC2/ECS:

- Lambda functions are prone to the Cold Start issue. A Cold Start issue usually occurs when a Lambda function hasn't been invoked for quite some time. AWS deploys a new container to the Lambda function in the backend, and there might be delayed invocations at times[3].
- It can get arduous to debug AWS Lambda function logs and metrics in Amazon CloudWatch.
- A Lambda function has a supported maximum execution time of 15 minutes, and there is a time period limitation. Therefore, it might not be possible to use a Lambda function for time-consuming operations(eg: Processing large flat files).

Amazon EC2 has a system administration payload and it might cost a bit higher, but there are no Lambda Cold Start issues, and it can even work for long running tasks. 
Therefore, you could choose to use EC2 or Lambda depending on your exact use-case.

I hope this answer helps you out.

## References

[1]. https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

[2]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html

[3]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda run as the stateless service, means, we can't store files inside the function. We built the whole application with the 60 lambda functions. Out of 60, 54 lambda functions are triggered by API gateway remaining are act as the service modules (means, called by another lambda function).

If you use lambda function as the microservice, you can gain more in the performance and price aspects.

My suggestion: Don't create a single lambda function to run the whole system. Go with microservices method.